# statvfs not behaving as expected

Tags: diskspace

I am using `statvfs()` to find out the available space on a uSD card. `statvfs()` returns expected results if I call it when the uSD card was plugged in from boot, but if I call `statvfs()` after I unplug the uSD `statvfs()` returns success and odd numbers for the number of blocks. If I call `statvfs()` when the uSD card was not plugged in from boot `statvfs()` correctly returns -1 for failure. Why doesn't `statvfs()` return -1 when I call it after I unplug the uSD? Is this a known issue?

Booted with uSD:
SUCCESS,
f_blocks:51091,
f_bsize:2048,
f_fsid:2049,
f_bfree:48922,
f_flag:3072

Removed uSD:
SUCCESS,
f_blocks:4096,
f_bsize:4096,
f_fsid:0,
f_bfree:4096,
f_flag:4096

Booted w/o uSD:
FAILURE

The uSD is 32 GB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment by "lurker" on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819484/linux-why-can-write-to-sd-card-that-has-been-removed) is what I was looking for on how to properly detect the uSD card being removed.